# One to one in rails aplication

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, associations

i have question about proper way to do one to one association in rails.
I am using Devise GEM as user module and all users can have only one company so i made

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :company
end
```

and

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What is proper way to create company?? normally i made it like this:
i check if company exist if exist display message if not proceed to create. Is that good method?

```
 def new
   if Company.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id )
     flash[:notice] = "Only One company is allowed."
     redirect_to(:action => 'index')
   end
 end

 def create   
   # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
   @company = Company.new(company_params)
   #@company = Company.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => 1))
   # Save the object
   if @company.save
     # If save succeeds, redirect to the index action
     flash[:notice] = "Company created successfully."
     redirect_to(:action => 'index')
   else
     # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
     render('new')
   end    
 end
```

Comment: Its fine do this way or you can add `has_company?` in user model.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is properly created, it should be OK.

in your User form, you should use [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), and it should look like something like this : 

`<%= f.fields_for :company do |company_field| %>
     <%= company_field.text_field :name %>
<% end %>`

Edit : Don't forget to add [nested attibutes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) : `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` on the model user, below the has_one :company.

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent.

Beside that, be carefull with the validation you wanted to do in the `new` method, the proper way to handle validation is to use [ActiveRecord Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).